# Group laws of the flow of time-dependent vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, vector-fields

I am reading the fundamental theorem on time-dependent flows from the book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, written by John Lee ([see page 237](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds/xygVcKGPsNwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Fundamental+theorem+of+time+dependent+flows&pg=PA237&printsec=frontcover)). The last line of the theorem (i.e., equation $9.18$) says that if $p\in M_{t_1,t_0}$ and $\psi_{t_1,t_0}(p)\in M_{t_2,t_1}$, then $p\in M_{t_2,t_0}$ and $$\psi_{t_2,t_1}\circ \psi_{t_1,t_0}(p)=\psi_{t_2,t_0}(p).$$

Notice that the left-hand side of this equation depends on $t_1$, but the right-hand side doesn't. Should it not be $$\psi_{t_2,t_1}\circ \psi_{t_0,t_1}(p)=\psi_{t_2+t_0,t_1}(p)?$$ The question arises while checking the group laws (i.e., equation $9.3$ on [page 209](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds/xygVcKGPsNwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Fundamental+theorem+of+time+dependent+flows&pg=PA209&printsec=frontcover)) of the flow of each vector field $V_t\colon M\to TM$ defined by $V_t(p)=V(t,p)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing the notations. With $\psi_t$ you'd be fine to add them. However this is $\psi_{t_0,t_1}$ which is actually the curve $\beta_{t_1-t_0}$ as explained on page 238. Note that $$\psi_{t_0,t_1} \circ \psi_{t_1,t_2} = \beta_{t_1-t_0} \circ \beta_{t_2-t_1} = \beta_{t_1-t_0+t_2-t_1} =\beta_{t_2-t_0} = \psi_{t_0,t_2}$$ as claimed. You can see how the group law was ultimately used to prove the result.

Comment: Actually, I am struggling to find the flow of each $V_{t}\colon M\to TM$ in terms of $\psi\colon J\times J\times M\to M$, assuming $M$ is compact. Could you please add this to your answer?